# Why is __wakeup() called on my object when I session_start()?

Tags: php, session, singleton

I have a following problem:

I use a class with singleton pattern, i made the __wakeup() private for that reason. At no point is that object being stored in session. When i call session_start(), i get this error message:

```
Warning: Invalid callback MySingletonClass::__wakeup, cannot access private method MySingletonClass::__wakeup() in Session.php on line 32
```

line 32 of Session.php reads:

```
30 public function startSession() {
31     if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
32         session_start();
33     }
34 }
```

I understand that objects stored in session are being serialized and unserialized, but MySingletonClass is never stored in session... In fact, the $_SESSION array is empty.

I was thinking that maybe i stored it in session by accident sometime and it sits there, but this persists even if i clear all $_SESSION data, destroy the session, delete session files on server, restart Apache and start new session...

What's even weirder is that i use several different classes that use exact same singleton pattern, have private __wakeup(), and they never raise this problem. Its just this one.

What is going on? Is my code so insane php got confused?

[edit]
I figured something out:

This error happens if `session_start()` is called AFTER the `MySingletonClass` has been defined (so after the file containing its definition has been included/required) but does not if `session_start()` is moved to the very beginning of script execution, before any other files are included/required.

Does anyone have an explanation here? Having `session_start()` earlier is fine I guess, I would start it anyhow, but I would like to know what is happening here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue - the problem was in my autoloading procedure. I think. Perhaps.

To be honest, **i have no clue** what was really wrong, but after i scrapped my autoloader class, and re-wrote it from scratch, the error message disappeared so i assume it was autoloader that was at fault.

Your guess is as good as mine.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem, with PHPUnit 5.7.27.

In my case, backupGlobals was set to "true". Setting it to false, in my phpunit.xml, fixed it.